# Count Non-NULL Elements Across Multiple Columns for Each Row

Tags: postgresql

## Back Story

I have an employee table where each employee has one or more work role(s) assigned to them, and for each assigned role it shows the year that it was assigned. I have a query that builds a matrix table, with one row per employee, like so:

| name | role1 | role2 | role3 | role4 | role5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bunny, Bugs |  |  |  |  | 2022 |
| Coyote, Wiley | 2018 |  |  | 2018 |  |
| Pig, Porky |  |  | 2017 |  |  |
| Mouse, Mickey |  |  |  | 2020 |  |
| Panther, Pink | 2019 |  |  |  |  |
| Cheese, Chuckey |  |  | 2021 | 2017 |  |
| Duck, Donald | 2021 |  |  | 2021 |  |
| Devil, Taz |  | 2019 |  |  |  |
| Brown, Charlie |  |  | 2021 |  | 2019 |
| Flintstone, Fred | 2019 |  | 2011 | 2016 |  |

## Summary Columns

I need to have some additional columns that compute the following for each employee:

1. Number of roles assigned to the employee (COUNT?)
2. The year of the oldest role assigned (LEAST)
3. The year of the most recent role assigned (GREATEST)

## Desired Results

This table illustrates the desired results of my analysis:

| name | role1 | role2 | role3 | role4 | role5 | role_count | role_oldest | role_newest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bunny, Bugs |  |  |  |  | 2022 | 1 | 2022 | 2022 |
| Coyote, Wiley | 2018 |  |  | 2015 |  | 2 | 2015 | 2018 |
| Pig, Porky |  |  | 2017 |  |  | 1 | 2017 | 2017 |
| Mouse, Mickey |  |  |  | 2020 |  | 1 | 2020 | 2020 |
| Panther, Pink | 2019 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2019 | 2019 |
| Cheese, Chuckey |  |  | 2021 | 2017 |  | 2 | 2017 | 2021 |
| Duck, Donald | 2021 |  |  | 2021 |  | 2 | 2021 | 2021 |
| Devil, Taz |  | 2019 |  |  |  | 1 | 2019 | 2019 |
| Brown, Charlie |  |  | 2021 |  | 2019 | 2 | 2019 | 2021 |
| Flintstone, Fred | 2019 |  | 2011 | 2016 |  | 3 | 2016 | 2019 |

## My Mixed Results

For the `role_oldest` and `role_newest` columns, I was able to use the following statements:

```
UPDATE employee_roles
  SET role_oldest = LEAST(role1, role2, role3, role4, role5);

UPDATE employee_roles
  SET role_newest = GREATEST(role1, role2, role3, role4, role5);
```

However, in iterative attempts at computing the role_count, I unsuccessfully tried various combinations of the `COUNT`, `ARRAY`, `UNNEST`and `STRING_TO_ARRAY` functions, like so:

```
UPDATE employee_roles
  SET role_count = COUNT(role1, role2, role3, role4, role5);
```

```
UPDATE employee_roles
  SET role_count = COUNT(UNNEST(role1, role2, role3, role4, role5));
```

```
UPDATE employee_roles
  SET role_count = COUNT(UNNEST(ARRAY(role1, role2, role3, role4, role5)));
```

```
UPDATE employee_roles
  SET role_count = COUNT(UNNEST(ARRAY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(role1, role2, role3, role4, role5))));
```

## Climbing Out of the Rabbit Hole

It is apparent that I am going the wrong way in this exercise, so I am pulling back out and seeking your help in this. I am sure there is indeed an elegant solution for this, and it is right under my nose, and I hope someone can help me find it.

## Similar Questions with Complicated Answers

I have found numerous other similar posts here on SO, and every one of them include crazy solutions that require lots of PSQL gymnastics, and I find it hard to believe that there is not a simple function that does this.

## Code for Creating Sample Table

The following code blocks will help quickly create the sample table for this exercise:

```
create table employee_roles
(
    name        text,
    role1       integer default null,
    role2       integer default null,
    role3       integer default null,
    role4       integer default null,
    role5       integer default null,
    role6       integer default null,
    role_count  integer default null,
    role_oldest integer default null,
    role_newest integer default null
);
```

```
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Bunny, Bugs',null,null,null,null,2022);
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Coyote, Wiley',2018,null,null,2018,null);
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Pig, Porky',null,null,2017,null,null);
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Mouse, Mickey',null,null,null,2020,null);
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Panther, Pink',2019,null,null,null,null);
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Cheese, Chuckey',null,null,2021,2017,null);
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Duck, Donald',2021,null,null,2021,null);
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Devil, Taz',null,2019,null,null,null);
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Brown, Charlie',null,null,2021,null,2019);
insert into employee_roles (name,role1,role2,role3,role4,role5)
    values ('Flintstone, Fred',2019,null,2011,2016,null);
```

Comment: You are looking for `num_nonnulls()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which version you're using (can you update?) -- in v. 14, it doesn't look like `GREATEST()` and `LEAST()` behave in the way you described.

You can try the following to get the `COUNT` output you're looking for:

```
edb=# select name, array_length(array_remove(array[role1,role2,role3,role4,role5],null),1) from employee_roles ;
       name       | array_length                                                                                
------------------+--------------                                                                               
 Bunny, Bugs      |            1                                                                                
 Coyote, Wiley    |            2                                                                                
 Pig, Porky       |            1                                                                                
 Mouse, Mickey    |            1                                                                                
 Panther, Pink    |            1                                                                                
 Cheese, Chuckey  |            2                                                                                
 Duck, Donald     |            2                                                                                
 Devil, Taz       |            1                                                                                
 Brown, Charlie   |            2                                                                                
 Flintstone, Fred |            3                                                                                
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Actually, I am using v. 13 (haven't had the time to upgrade to n14), and here is the documentation in section 9.18.4: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html.  I will try your solution tomorrow, for sure!

Comment: I love how you first extracted all the nulls from the array then counted the remaining elements.